# How to derive this MAE error bound on the central limit theorem?

Tags: error, central-limit-theorem, bounds, iid, mean-absolute-deviation

[image: tral]

Is this derived from Chebyshev's inequality or a tail bound theorem? If not, how was it derived?
Does this require the existence of the third moment? 
Does this bound suggest the normal approximation is not very good?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

Comment: Well, in that formula you copied you see the use of third moments, so they sure must exist for the formula to be of any use ...